# Context.CurrentMiningModel returns null in UDF

Tags: c#, ssas, sql-server-2012, adomd.net

I migrated Mining Structures from a 2008 server to a 2012 server. When I try my CLR UDF (which is working fine on SQL server 2008) in a DMX query on the 2012 server, I am getting this error:

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

My original goal was to get the [GetNodeDescription(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.analysisservices.adomdserver.context.currentminingmodel%28v=sql.110%29.Aspx) method running. While debugging the problem, I could isolate the problem to this UDF which fails on my SQL server 2012

```
[SafeToPrepare(true)]
public static string test()
{
  return Context.CurrentMiningModel.Name;
}
```

My guess is that `CurrentMiningModel` is null because the following code works fine

```
[SafeToPrepare(true)]
public static string testUser()
{
 return Context.CurrentConnection.User.Name;
}
```

Any Idea on how to solve this?
Is somebody out there who can reproduce this?

Thanks.

Jan

UPDATE:
A contact at Microsoft confirmed this behaviour as desired due to a "Metadata-Refactoring" (whatever this means...). However, the [website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.analysisservices.adomdserver.context.currentminingmodel%28v=sql.110%29.Aspx) still pends to be updated appropiately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the ultimate answer but it's a workaround to get Microsoft's [GetNodeDescription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.analysisservices.adomdserver.context.currentminingmodel%28v=sql.110%29.Aspx) working (by explicitly providing the mining model):

```
[SafeToPrepare(true)]  
public static string GetNodeDescription(string MiningModel, string nodeUniqueName)  
{  
  if (Context.ExecuteForPrepare)  
  {
    return string.Empty;  
  }  
  return Context.MiningModels[MiningModel].GetNodeFromUniqueName(nodeUniqueName).Descript‌​ion;  
}
```